# Animating Graph in Oracle ADF using Jdeveloper

Tags: oracle12c, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

[This is an example of an animated graph. I want to replicate this](https://canvasjs.com/javascript-charts/animated-chart/)

Comment: Your question isn't complete. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and complete your question with what you tried. Did you tried using Oracle ADF Data Visualizations Graph available in the component palette?

Comment: I have tried that but I am facing that the graph is coming as an image but I want it to be interactive.

Comment: If you don't like the default adf graph component you can simply add you own canvajs library to your page

Comment: But that is what I am not looking for.